# User-level vs system-level limits on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wrote a small program that opens a bunch of files and played with open files limit on Ubuntu(as root). I was surprised to see that only user-level limits had effect on max number of files open.

I added this in /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
root hard nofile 30000
root soft nofile 30000
```

And set /proc/sys/fs/file-max to 20000 (`sysctl -w fs.file-max=20000`).

I then ran my program to open 29000 files without any problems.

Why does not system-level setting have any effect in this case?

Comment: Have you restarted/started a new session after modifying `limits.conf` ?

Comment: @BatchyX Yep, I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, to recap -

**user-level limits** on Linux are set in /etc/security/limits.conf (or under /limits.d dir)

**system-level** limits are set in /etc/sysctl.conf (immediately changed by a command like this: `sysctl -w fs.file-max=20000`)

In my initial test system-level limit of open files was ignored because I was running my program as **root** , so it was a privileged process and **privileged processes on Linux bypass all kernel permission checks** (http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)